# Wix - Using XSLT to stop a directory being removed on uninstall

Tags: xslt, wix, windows-installer, uninstallation

My MSI installer will bundle in a load of additional files to get installed. This works fine, however, on uninstall / upgrade we want to keep these files.

Because they are bundled in and not components I can't use the usual way of stating to make components permanent.

I've found the following code which will identify files in the install directory and make them permanent

```
 <xsl:if test="contains(*[local-name()='File']/@Source, 'PCSTDESC')">
   <xsl:attribute name="NeverOverwrite"><xsl:text>yes</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
   <xsl:attribute name="Permanent"><xsl:text>yes</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>        
 </xsl:if>
```

However this is for a specific file where as in my example there won't be a specific file or extension, I just want to keep the whole 'Documents' Directory

I've tried the following but haven't had any luck with it yet

```
<xsl:if test="contains(*[local-name()='Directory']/@Name, 'Documents')">
  <xsl:attribute name="NeverOverwrite"><xsl:text>yes</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="Permanent"><xsl:text>yes</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Any suggestions on how to get it working as expected?

Comment: Could you make all the files under the Directory permanent? Something like `<xsl:if test="contains(parent::*[local-name()='Directory']/@Name, 'Documents')">`?

Comment: What files are these? Why doesn't your application create them? You could keep read-only templates under INSTALLDIR that you copy to the user's "My Documents" folder when needed?

Comment: @TimC this has worked if you would like to put it as an answer, note though that if the directory are empty they will get removed, only if there is a file in the directory they are kept

Comment: I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you mark a directory as permanent, but you could try marking all files within the directory instead.

Try this...

```
<xsl:if test="contains(parent::*[local-name()='Directory']/@Name, 'Documents')">
```

Comment: This worked for my scenario, as i mentioned in my comment above, if the folders inside the directory is empty, then it is still removed, but if the folders contain any files, then they are kept. Which is a perfect result